# How to Handle Dynamically Changing ID in Selenum

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a drop down menu which changes its id after clicking it

[image]

Here is the HTML code before clicking on it (This code is grayed out {hidden} in page).

```
 <a class="headet_fonts" href="http://192.168.1.6/eprint_prod_3.8/ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx" onmouseout="javascript:displaynone('#FFFFFF');" onmouseover="javascript:onhovermenu('ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx','Products','Products',tabcolor,headerforecolor)">
  <b>
    <span id="**ctl00_header1_upperRepeater_ctl10_ModuleName**" class="headet_fonts header_colorbalck" style="color:black;">
      Products
    </span>
    <input id="ctl00_header1_upperRepeater_ctl10_hdn_Forecolor" type="hidden" value="#FFFFFF" name="ctl00$header1$upperRepeater$ctl10$hdn_Forecolor">
  </b>
</a>
```

HTML code after clicking on it (This code is not hidden):

```
<a class="headet_fonts" href="http://192.168.1.6/eprint_prod_3.8/ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx" onmouseout="javascript:displaynone('#FFFFFF');" onmouseover="javascript:onhovermenu('ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx','Products','navbar',tabcolor,'#FFFFFF')">
  <b>
    <span id="ctl00_header1_upperRepeater_ctl10_ActiveModuleName" class="ActiveModulenavigatorpanel" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
      Products
    </span>
  </b>
</a>
```

In Selenium code I used xpath:

```
//div[@id='Products']/a/b/span
```

to locate it but it is showing `NoSuchElementException`. I can't use ID since it is changing

Comment: @Santosh: Do make sure that you format your question post content properly before posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a different xpath, you are not limited to the one you showed.

You can use xpath's `contains()` function, for example:

```
//span[contains(@id, 'ctl00_header1_upperRepeater_ctl10')]
```

Or try to select the `span` via the `a` tag:

```
//a[@class=='headset_fonts']//span
//a[contains(@href, 'ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx')]//span
```

For developing these xpaths, use something that immediately shows you results (e.g. the XPath Checker addon for Firefox). That way you should quickly arrive at a working xpath.

Comment: I am Getting this error while running selenium script
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//a[contains(@href, 'ProductCatalogue/PriceCatalogue.aspx')]//span"}
Command duration or timeout: 1.06 seconds

Comment: As I said, don't develop your xpath over selenium. Get a working xpath first using XPather, Xpath Checker, or whatever tool you prefer, then plug that into your code.

Answer (score 1):

From the html we can conclude that the anchor tag will be visible on `onmouseover` event. So you just have to use [`Action`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class `movetoelement()` method to hover over the header.And then use `findElement()` with

```
xpath = //div[@id='Products']//span[contains(.,'Products')]
```

or

Since its within an anchor tag, you can use `linkText` as well :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Products")).click();
```

---

One more simpler method would be to use `JavascripExecuter`, using this you dont have to hover to make the element visible, because this will work on hidden elements as well, though i don't recommend this (reason - users wont click on hidden elements). The following script is just for your knowledge :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('div#Products span').click();");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only providing this as an alternative:  Use **CSS** *not* xpath.  CSS is cleaner, simpler, and faster.

```
span[id^='ctl00_header1_upperRepeater']
```

I just can't condone the other answers.  Xpath is complicated and unnecessary for something of this caliber.